# How to mention that a specific time is already over?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-request, conditional-constructions, time

> If it is already over 9:35 pm, I will close the main door.

Is this correct? I want to express that , if a specific time is over then I won't allow any one to enter into the hostel.

Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: Use *past* (or *later than*, though that's less common) rather than "already over". We don't usually talk of clock-times being "over" (it makes sense, we just don't do it). Also consider checking out our cool sister site, [ELL.se].

Comment: Sorry, one question per post please. I've rolled back your edit. If you want to ask the other question about *at* vs *in*, I suggest you do so on [ELL.se], as I suggested in my first comment.

Comment: `If it is past 9:35 pm, I will close the main door.`- is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Usually - *The main door is locked at 9.35pm*.

Comment: I think you are perhaps thinking of something (an event) *being over by* a given time. It is not the time that is *over*; it is the event. In this context, *over* just means *finished*: *If the movie is over by 9:30 then...*.

Comment: @DanBron -- Your comments would make a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

People tend to use

> When it is *past* x o' clock, I will...

Rather than using

> When it is *over* x o' clock, I will...

"Past" suggests that time has moved forward in comparison to the specified time, while "over" seems to suggest that time has somehow moved upwards, which doesn't make a lot of sense.